# Python Argparse: Get the command-line argument used for a Namespace variable

Tags: python, argparse

Is there a proper, or at least better, way to get which command-line argument was used to set an Namespace argument (attribute) value?

I am currently using something like this:

```py
>>> import argparse
>>>
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--do-a', '-a',
...     default=False, action='store_true',
...     dest='process_foo',
...     help="Do some awesome a to the thing.")
>>> args = parser.parse_args()
>>>
>>> def get_argument(parser, dest):
...     for action in parser._actions:
...         if action.dest == dest:
...             return action.option_strings[0], action.help
...     return dest, ''
...
>>> get_argument(parser, 'process_foo')
('--do-a', 'Do some awesome a to the thing.')
```

This will probably work in 99% of cases; however, if more than one command-line argument can set `process_foo`, this wont work, and accessing a 'hidden' instance attribute (`parser._actions`) is kludgy at best. Is there a better way to do this?

I'm adding this to a module that all data science processes inherit which logs environment and other things so that we have better reproducibility. The module in question already auto-logs settings, parameters, command-line arguments, etc. but is not very user friendly in some aspects.

Comment: Why not just use `args.process_foo`? Does that not work for your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry about the "hiddenness" of `_actions`.  That is the primary list where references to all `Actions` created by `add_argument` are stored.  You shouldn't fiddle with the list, but you certainly can use it to collect information.

`add_argument` creates an `Action` object, puts it in `_actions` (via the `_add_action` method), and also returns it.  If you don't like using `_actions` you can collect your own list of references, using the object returned by `add_argument`.

I see from `_add_action` that it also puts flagged actions in a `self._option_string_actions` dict, making it easier to pair an option string with its `action`.

Parsing does not make any changes to the `parser`, its attributes or the `actions`.  While it has various local variables (in the `_parse_known_args` method), the only thing that is changed is the `args` Namespace.

It keeps the access to `args` as generic as possible, with `getattr`, `setattr` and `hasattr`.  This includes setting the defaults at the start of parsing.  The parser does not maintain a record of which option-string triggered a particular `take_action` and subsequent `setattr`.  However the `__call__` of an `Action` does get the string. For the most common 'store_action' the call is

```
def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
    setattr(namespace, self.dest, values)
```

I think all defined `Action` subclasses use the `self.dest`, but user defined ones don't have to.  They can even set other namespace attributes, or none (e.g. help doesn't set anything).  They could also record the `option_string`.

It is also possible to set a namespace attribute without going through the defined Actions.  Your `dest` test won't help with these.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#parser-defaults

shows how attributes can be set without defining them in an argument. Subcommands shows how this can be used to define a function that will be used with a particular parser.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-namespace-object
also shows that it's possible to supply a partially initialize namespace.

Comment: Thanks hpaulj. This worked well for what I needed (inferring argparse information from a module imported and which automagically logs the state of the running process).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating your own action class derived from [argarse.Action](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action-classes) that will not only store the parsed value in the namespace, but also store the parsed value's option string in the namespace.

Full working example:

```py
import argparse

class StoreTrueWithOptionStringAction(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self,
                 option_strings,
                 dest,
                 default=None,
                 required=False,
                 help=None,
                 metavar=None):
        super().__init__(option_strings=option_strings,
                         dest=dest,
                         nargs=0,
                         const=True,
                         default=default,
                         required=required,
                         help=help)
    
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, self.const)
        if option_string is not None:
            setattr(namespace, f'{self.dest}_option_string', option_string)

def get_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--bar', action=StoreTrueWithOptionStringAction, dest='foo', default=False)
    parser.add_argument('--baz', action=StoreTrueWithOptionStringAction, dest='foo', default=False)
    return parser

def main():
    parser = get_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args.foo)
    print(args.foo_option_string)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```sh
$ python3 main.py --bar
True
--bar
$ python3 main.py --baz
True
--baz
```

Comment: Thanks jisrael. I think your answer is best for most use cases; however, I was writing a module that saves the command-line args and the argparse state (default vs. actuals, etc) in a way that required only importing it and it "did all the magic". @hpaulj 's answer might be a bit more  "risky" (I've already run into some edge cases, but it's still good enough for me),  but it works really well for that purpose.